# DiscordAPIError[undefined]: No Description

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I am currently building a music bot for my Discord channel, but I keep getting an error when trying to load the commands. This error has so far appeared on all the bots that I am trying to build even the most basic. Here is the example code that I used straight off of the Discord Documentation:

```
const { REST, Routes } = require("discord.js");
const { Client, GatewayIntentBits } = require("discord.js");
const client = new Client({ intents: [GatewayIntentBits.Guilds] });

const CLIENT_ID = "ID";

const TOKEN =
  "token";

const commands = [
  {
    name: "ping",
    description: "Replies with Pong!",
  },
];

const rest = new REST({ version: "10" }).setToken(TOKEN);

(async () => {
  try {
    await rest.put(Routes.applicationCommands(CLIENT_ID), {
      headers: { authorization: `Bot ${TOKEN}` },
      body: commands,
    });

  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
})();

client.on("ready", () => {
  console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);
});

client.on("interactionCreate", async (interaction) => {
  if (!interaction.isChatInputCommand()) return;

  if (interaction.commandName === "ping") {
    await interaction.reply("Pong!");
  }
});

client.login(TOKEN);
```

I am getting the following error:

```
DiscordAPIError[undefined]: No Description
    at SequentialHandler.runRequest (...\MusicBot\node_modules\@discordjs\rest\dist\lib\handlers\SequentialHandler.cjs:293:15)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async SequentialHandler.queueRequest (...\MusicBot\node_modules\@discordjs\rest\dist\lib\handlers\SequentialHandler.cjs:99:14)
    at async REST.request (...\React\MusicBot\node_modules\@discordjs\rest\dist\lib\REST.cjs:52:22)
    at async ...\MusicBot\index.js:24:5 {
  rawError: Uint8Array(155) [
     60, 104, 116, 109, 108,  62,  13,  10,  60, 104, 101,  97,
    100,  62,  60, 116, 105, 116, 108, 101,  62,  52,  48,  48,
     32,  66,  97, 100,  32,  82, 101, 113, 117, 101, 115, 116,
     60,  47, 116, 105, 116, 108, 101,  62,  60,  47, 104, 101,
     97, 100,  62,  13,  10,  60,  98, 111, 100, 121,  62,  13,
     10,  60,  99, 101, 110, 116, 101, 114,  62,  60, 104,  49,
     62,  52,  48,  48,  32,  66,  97, 100,  32,  82, 101, 113,
    117, 101, 115, 116,  60,  47, 104,  49,  62,  60,  47,  99,
    101, 110, 116, 101,
    ... 55 more items
  ],
  code: undefined,
  status: 400,
  method: 'PUT',
  url: 'https://discord.com/api/v9/applications/1021797370285010954/commands',
  requestBody: { files: undefined, json: undefined }
}
```

Comment: Your requestBody has undefined files & json content.
Why do you instantiate the Client with GatewayIntentBits.Guilds ? Your command is supposed to be for a guild channel ?

Comment: Yes, I need the bot to be able to post a message when the user writes the command. I am not sure why the requestBody is empty, this is almost the exact code example that is documented on the Discord Documentation. Normally it is only the files that is undefined and the json is populated by an [Object] which is correct I believe

Comment: It's been a while since I did a Discord bot, but I think you need to set the GuildId too like so : 
await rest.put(
            Routes.applicationGuildCommands(process.env.CLIENT_ID, process.env.GUILD_ID),
            { body: commands },
        )

Comment: Nope, didn't work in this case, same error Unfortunately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So seems the solution was by removing the headers:

```
headers: { authorization: `Bot ${TOKEN}` },
```

from the payload and clearing my cache with `npm cache clean –force` , my issue was resolved after I did this.